# What's the difference between Send and ControlSend?

Tags: autohotkey

AutoHotkey's official documentation lists two different sets of commands for sending simulated keyboard input to a window.

> #### [Send / SendRaw / SendInput / SendPlay / SendEvent](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)
>
> Sends simulated keystrokes and mouse clicks to the active window.

> #### [ControlSend / ControlSendRaw](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)
>
> Sends simulated keystrokes to a window or control.

---

- What's the difference between Send and ControlSend?
- Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send/SendXXX commands send input to the **active window**. That is the window that currently has **focus**, usually by clicking it with your mouse, tabbing to it, or when a window sets focus to itself.

If your AHK script were to target a Notepad window that you have open, and you were to click on another window such as Chrome, your inputs would now be sent to Chrome.

On the flipside, using ControlSend/ControlSendXXX commands will send input to a specified **window** or **control**. A control might be a textbox, button, or similar interactive elements.

Here, the above example would *still output to Notepad* even if you switched focus to another window such as Chrome. The downside is that you must specify which control to send to.

Comment: So, shouldn't `Send, 1` (Send 1 to the active window) be the same as `ControlSend, , 1, A` (send 1 to the window A which is a constant that returns the active window)? For the thing that I'm testing now, `Send, 1` works but `ControlSend, , 1, A` does nothing.